# Firebase Cloud Messaging Only Seeing Last Notification on Android

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM to send data push notifications to android devices via HTTP protocol. If I send several notifications, phone chimes that many times but I only only see the last notification that was sent in the notifications tray. I am NOT using the collapse_key so they should show up individually. Here is the payload:

```
{  
   "data":{  
      "testId":"3",
      "test2Id":"2",
      "title":"Test Alert Title 1",
      "body":"Test Alert Body 1"
   },
   "to":"DEVICE_REG_ID_XXXX"
}
```

**UPDATE:**
On the device side, we're using phonegap-cordova-push plugin (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/tree/v1.9.x) in our Cordova app.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think it cares about a collapse_key if you send `data` but not `notification` data. Your app handles everything manually

Comment: How you are creating notification when you receive FCM? Are you using different notification id or same?

Comment: We're using phonegap-cordova-push plugin (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/tree/v1.9.x) in our Cordova app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We were able to figure out the issue so I am posting for others who may have the same issue. The problem was with the plugin in question. Looking at the plugin code, we determined that the plugin was expecting attribute `notId` in the data payload to mark each notification as unique otherwise they'd get collapsed and only the latest would show up in the notification tray. So payload should like this:

```
{  
   "data":{  
      "testId":"3",
      "test2Id":"2",
      "title":"Test Alert Title 1",
      "body":"Test Alert Body 1"
      "notId":"45"
   },
   "to":"DEVICE_REG_ID_XXXX"
}
```

And sender needs to ensure that each FCM request has unique `notId` attribute.